# Listen to multiple ports only apply to localhost but not external ip of the server

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, port, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running apache on google compute engine and I follow the step here : http://www.groovypost.com/howto/apache/configure-apache-web-site-to-use-multiple-ports/

to enable my website to accept multiple port other than the default port80 , but it seems like it only apply to localhost only but not my ip address:

I used `telnet localhost 8080` and it works but why when I used `telnet <my-external-ip-address> 8080` it wouldn't works. Can I know why?

Comment: Please post the httpd.conf for that virtual host

Comment: This is likely an iptables issue. Please post the output of "sudo iptables -L" (after sanitising it, if you feel there's any information in there you would rather not be seen).

Comment: you have to open port 8080 in google cloud firewall to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Rupeshkumar do you know how could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In the httpd.conf file, if you have given Listen as:

```
    Listen localhost:8080
```

change it to:

```
    Listen 8080
```

then it will bind the server socket to all available IP addresses on the system.
If that is not the case, try looking into the IP tables.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open port 8080 in google cloud firewall to resolve this issue.

To open firewall in google cloud go to:

1. Menu
2. Networking
3. Firewalls Rules
4. Create firewall
   source ip add 0.0.0.0
   port add tcp:8080

*Note: if u leave blank in target tags it will enable in all vms, so if you want to add tag specify that and add same tag in vm by editing vm.*